# Flutter get json data by index

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter and I have a `JSON` like below:

```
var json = {
  "key1": {"key": [1,2,3]},
  "key2": {"key": [4,5,7]},
  "key3": {"key": [8,9,10]},
}
```

I know that, for example, I can retrieve `{"key": [4,5,7]}` just by calling `json["key2"]`.

But i'm asking, is it possible to retrieve it by using its index position, just like `json[1]`?

Comment: @someuser Actually `"key1", "key2"` etc, are sample key names for this example. In reality, the `"key1", "key2"` etc, are unique id values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, change your json to:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "key": [1,2,3]
    },
    {
      "key": [4,5,7]
    },
    {
      "key": [8,9,10]
    }
  ]
}
```

And access it like: `parsedJson["values"][0]`

In case you don't want to change your data structure, you can still do it like:

```
import 'dart:core';

void main() {
  var json = {
  "key1": {"key": [1,2,3]},
  "key2": {"key": [4,5,7]},
  "key3": {"key": [8,9,10]},
  };
  
  List<Map<String, List<int>>> jsonObjects = [];
  
  for (final name in json.keys) {
    final value = json[name];
    print('$value');
    jsonObjects.add(value);
  }
  
  print('$jsonObjects');
  
  print('Second object: ${jsonObjects[1]}');
}
```

You can try this at https://dartpad.dev

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm getting these data from firebase, so it would be much better if I didn't have to restructure my data, in order to use the solution you recommended.

Comment: Ok, in that case, you must make an array of your "key" object and append every key to it, then you are good to go with accessing them by using index :D

Comment: That's a great idea. If you want, edit your answer above and include this solution too, so I can accept your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you, I will include it now

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can try this solution on Dartpad too :D